# Reconocer enlase - efecto (mini-Markdown)

Tags: php

Trate de hacer mi propio **mini-Markdown** con **PHP** y la verdad no esta tan mal, pero me esta faltando reconocer los enlases de este modo: `[enlace](http://example.com)`, y no logro hacerlo o me da errores. Tengo otra funcion que reconoce los `https` y `http`, pero al trate de unir todo se rompe el script:

```
<?php
function miniedit($text) {
    //negrita
    $pattern = '/(_(.*?)_)/';
    $replace = '<em>${2}</em>';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);

    //italica
    $pattern = '/(\*(.*?)\*)/';
    $replace = '<strong>${2}</strong>';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);

    //code
    $pattern = '/(\`(.*?)\`)/';
    $replace = '<span style="background-color: #f1f1f1; font-family: Monospace; font-size: .8rem; padding: .3rem;">${2}</span>';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);

    // a partir de esta linea da error

    //enlase
    $pattern = '/(\[(.*?)\])/';
    $replace = '<a href="#">${2}</a>';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);


    return $text;
}

$prueba = '<span style="font-size: 20px;">*texto con negrita*, texto `natural` y *_`texto con negrita e itali y con fondo gris`_*</span>';

echo miniedit($prueba);
?>
```

Y esta es la funcion que reconce los enlaces `https` y `http`:

```
<?php
function findReplaceURL($text){
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url1)){
        return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='".$url1[0]."' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a>", $text);
        } else {
        return $text;
    }
}
?>
```

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda!

Comment: Por que no mejor usas [Parsedown](https://parsedown.org) así no te lías tanto, o te basas en los métodos y regex

Comment: Gracias, pero prefiero hacerlo por mi cuenta y aprender... se que es mas facil usar algo que ya esta hecho, pero me gusta saber hasta donde puedo llegar... gracias igual por la recomendacion!